# Как исправить ошибку expected an indented block?

Tags: python

Вот мой "код" и при каждом run у меня вылетает ошибка  expected an indented block как я понял ошибка в отступе.Я изменил отступы как было сказано в форумах и ничего не помогает.Пожалуйста помогите!

```
def my_name():
    my_name=input("Введите новое имя: ")
def math(x,y):
if operation=='+':
     print(x + y)
elif operation=='-':
     return x - y
elif operation=='*':
     return x * y
elif operation=='/':
     return x / y
else:
print("введите правильный символ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильные отступы таковы:

```
def my_name():
    my_name=input("Введите новое имя: ")

def math(x,y):
    if operation=='+':
        print(x + y)
    elif operation=='-':
        return x - y
    elif operation=='*':
        return x * y
    elif operation=='/':
        return x / y
    else:
        print("введите правильный символ")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

А правильный «калькулятор» таков:

```
import operator

ops = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.truediv,
    '%' : operator.mod,
    '**' : operator.pow,
}

def math(x, y, op):
    return ops.get(op)(x, y)

print(math(5, 6, '+')) # 11
print(math(5, 6, '*')) # 30
print(math(5, 6, '**')) # 15625
```